# Passing multiple dictionary arguments to query SQLLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Trying to create a Python program for quiz management. The questions are stored in a SQLLite database. Each questions has an ID, Marks field (along with other fields). The intention is that the admin can use the **formulate()** function to pass arguments on how many questions they want of each marks. For e.g. the quiz DB has questions with 3 marks, 5 marks and 10 marks each score. So if an admin wants to select 2 questions of 3 marks, 4 questions of 5 marks and 1 question of 10 marks, they can simply use

**formulate ([2,3] [4,5] [1,10])** and the function will be able to pull random questions for each count.

I am also looking to use a constructor to get some practice on the OOP side of things. I have managed to get it working with a singe set i.e **formulate([2,3])** , but I am not sure how to go about allowing multiple marks groups in a single argument. Also not sure how to use constructor properly.

```
def __init__(self, quizparam):
    self._quizpaper = quizparam
    quizparam[key]

    
def formulate(quizparam):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("QuizApp.DB") 
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql_query = "SELECT id, key FROM questions WHERE marks = ('%d') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ('%d') "%(quizparam[0],quizparam[1])
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    out = cur.fetchall()
    variable = {key:val for key,val in out}
    print(variable)
    conn.close()
```

Here is my output for a single argument set

[image]

This is my SQL Lite DB

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points to address here.  Let's consider these:

- How to query the database
- How to run our function with multiple arguments
- Another potential approach

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for regarding using a constructor and the `__init__` function.  That might be more complexity than we need here, so let's focus on getting the `formulate` function working for now.

#### Parameterized Query

Your SQLite query uses string substitution to specify the "marks" value and the query limit.  This can work, but it's best practice to use a parameterized query.  Basically, we can just use `?` in the SQL text and then provide the substitution values in the `cur.execute()` call.  The database itself handles substituting the values.

Instead of this:

```py
sql_query = "SELECT id, key FROM questions WHERE marks = ('%d') ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ('%d') "%(quizparam[0],quizparam[1])
cur.execute(sql_query)
```

Try this:

```py
sql_query = "SELECT id, key FROM questions WHERE marks=? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ?;"
cur.execute(sql_query, (quizparam[0], quizparam[1]))
```

#### Flexible Function Arguments

Your `formulate` function can work for one argument, but to give it the flexibility to accept multiple arguments, we'll need to change from:

```py
def forumlate(quizparam):
```

To this:

```py
def formulate(*quizparams):
```

The `*` allows the function to accept an arbitrary number of arguments that `quizparams` then captures.

The following function will handle one or more arguments by looping through the provided `[num_q, marks]` arguments stored in `quizparams`.

```py
def formulate(*quizparams):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("QuizApp.DB")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    results = []  # will be a list of tuples of form [(id, key), (id, key), ...]
    # now loop through the arguments
    # also, unpack each argument pair into "num_question" and "marks" variables
    for num_q, marks in quizparams:
        sql_query = "SELECT id, key FROM questions WHERE marks=? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT ?;"
        cur.execute(sql_query, (marks, num_q))  # parameterized query
        results.extend(cur.fetchall())
    conn.close()

    print(results)

formulate([2,3], [1,5])
>>> [(1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 3)]
```

#### Alternative Approach

The above `formulate` function works great for the need you described.  The database handles pulling the ids and keys we request along with the randomizing and limiting of results.  If you had an enormous number of quiz questions (like hundreds of thousands), then this may definitely be the best solution.

Personally though, I often prefer to minimize database interaction code and handle more of the logic using Python.  The below solution uses the "easy_db" library I wrote to simplify database work.  Just install it with pip:

```
pip install easy_db
```

The following function simplifies interaction with our database and applies the logic in Python rather than SQL.  Additionally, we are pulling the entire row of data for each question.

*As I imagine you need the actual question details, why not pull all of the info at once rather than going back and querying the database a second time with the ids and keys provided by your `formulate` function?*

```py
import easy_db
import random

def alternate_formulate(*quizparams):
    db = easy_db.DataBase("QuizApp.DB")  # connect to the database
    questions = db.pull("questions")  # get the "questions" table as a list of dicts
    random.shuffle(questions)  # randomize the order of questions

    results = []
    for num_q, marks in quizparams:
        # filter to rows with correct marks and limit number of rows to num_q
        subset = [row for row in questions if row["marks"] == marks][:num_q]
        results.extend(subset)
    
    print(results)

alternative_formulate([2,3], [1,5])
>>>[{'id': 2, 'question': 'What city...', 'key': 4, 'marks': 3, ...},
    {'id': 1, 'question': 'What is the...', 'key': 1, 'marks': 3, ...},
    {'id': 3, 'question': 'Which animal...', 'key': 3, 'marks': 5, ...}]
```